# Resque multiple workers in development mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, background, resque

Hi is it possible to run multiple Resque workers simultaneously in development? I found this bit of code, but not sure if it will work and how..

http://pastebin.com/9GKk8GwR

So far I am using the standard

```
bundle exec env rake resque:work QUEUE='*'

redis-server /usr/local/etc/redis.conf
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You need to add a `COUNT` environment variable and then change `resque:work` to `resque:workers`. For example, to start 3 workers:

```
bundle exec env rake resque:workers QUEUE='*' COUNT='3'
```

Comment: This is amazing! I've always had 3-5 separate console tabs open for with one worker in each. Now I can bunch them all into one tab. Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

The only way I know how to do that, and I think it's a great way, it's using Foreman (same thing that heroku uses).

You define your processes in a file named **Procfile** like:

```
web:    bundle exec thin start -p $PORT
worker: bundle exec rake resque:work QUEUE=*
clock:  bundle exec rake resque:scheduler
```

And then you can start your app with just one command

```
foreman start
```

To start more than one process of one type it's like this:

```
foreman start -c worker=2
```

---

https://github.com/ddollar/foreman

http://blog.daviddollar.org/2011/05/06/introducing-foreman.html

Comment: To start web worker as well use this: `foreman start -c web=1,worker=2`